# jQuery hide() not hiding div

Tags: jquery, html

I have the problem is a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/luisfalcon/wPEhW/

Basically if you try to close the window it won't do it.

If I remove the show() section of the js it will close it!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#printer").click(function () {
        $("#printerMenu").show();
    });
    $("#printerMenuClose").click(function () {
        $("#printerMenu").hide();
    });
});
```

Something tells me that this is a very simple fix but I can't find the answer!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

printerMenuClose click event bubbles up and it shows the printerMenu again. To hide it stop the event propagation.

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#printer").click(function () {
        $("#printerMenu").show();
    });
    $("#printerMenuClose").click(function (e) {
        $("#printerMenu").hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wPEhW/7/)

You can also read more about event propagation:

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: After a few minutes reading about event bubbling and event capture I finally got it, thank you very much Alok...

Answer (score 3):

use `e.stopPropagation();` to stop event **[bubbling](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**

```
 $("#printerMenuClose").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();  // Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree
    $("#printerMenu").hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/wPEhW/10/)

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, `<div id="printer">Open Me </div>`

The `printer` div in your code was the parent for the printer menu, so clicking any child would also cause the click event to be fired. You can change the HTML so that it no longer the parent for the `printer menu` div. This is called event bubbling.

```
<div id="printer">Open Me </div>
  <div id="printerMenu" class="menuPOP">
    <div class="menuPOPTit">Example Title
        <div id="printerMenuClose" class="menuPOPTitClose">Close Me</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/wPEhW/14/

Answer (score 3):

Try this below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#printer").click(function () {
        $("#printerMenu").show();
    });
    $("#printerMenuClose").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();//Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
        $("#printerMenu").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to make two changes in the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#printer").click(function () {
        $("#printerMenu").show();
    });
    $("#printerMenuClose").click(function (e) { //Add the event variable e
        $("#printerMenu").hide();
        e.stopPropagation(); //stop the event from bubbling to the parent
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/
When you click the' close me' the click event of the parent also gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wPEhW/12/)

```
<div id="printer"> 
     <span class="open">Open Me</span>
    <div id="printerMenu" class="menuPOP">
        <div class="menuPOPTit">Example Title
            <div id="printerMenuClose" class="menuPOPTitClose">Close Me</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".open").click(function () {
        $("#printerMenu").show();
    });
    $("#printerMenuClose").click(function () {
        $("#printerMenu").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: What if we have more elements of class `open` won't it still opens the menu ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#printer").click(function () {
        $("#printerMenu").show();
    });
    $("#printerMenuClose").click(function () {
       // $("#printerMenu").hide();
        $("#printerMenu").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
});
```

Comment: `.show()` function changes the `display` style of the element, it won't have any effect of using `visibility`. try to fiddle it.